# What do I use instead of Whitebox in Mockito 2.2 to set fields?

Tags: java, tdd, mockito, junit4, powermock

When using Mockito 1.9.x I have been using `Whitebox`to set values of fields to "inject" mocks. Se example below:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {

    eventHandler = new ProcessEventHandler();
    securityService = new SecurityServiceMock();
    registrationService = mock(RegistrationService.class);

    Whitebox.setInternalState(eventHandler, "registrationService", registrationService);
    Whitebox.setInternalState(eventHandler, "securityService", securityService);
}
```

I really like this approach, but now that I tried to upgrade to `Mockito`  `2.2.7` I noticed (or rather, my IDE noticed and told me quite a few times) that Whitebox was no longer to be found in Mockito.

<del>I have found one alternative, that can work as a replacement, and that is `org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox`, the problem with that is that I get another dependency (Powermock), just to use Whitebox.</del>

`Powermock` also have a class named `Whitebox`, but unfortunately  it looks as if it can not be used with `Mockito 2.2.x`

Is there any good alternatives in Mockito that I can use to manually "inject" fields, now that `Whitebox` is no longer available?

---

### Solution

I wrote in a comment in response to the post made of @JeffBowman. In short I chose to copy the code of WhiteBox, and use that, since it is used in most of the test cases and the class does not have dependencies to other classes. It was the fastest path to solve this issue.

**Note** The solution that @bcody suggest is a better alternative, if you are using spring, it ads no extra code for you to maintain. I got that information to late :(

Comment: Does Mockito's @InjectMocks annotation not help?

Comment: I don't know how they work in 2.2. In 1.x my experience is that if they for some reason fail to inject mockito is silent and I get a NullPointerException in the class where the injection failed. When using whitebox I get a exception clearly telling me that it failed. I started by using @InjectMocks, but thought that WhiteBox was better, so did my co-workers, so now we have a lot of code that is using WhiteBox, making upgrade timeconsuming, if we need to do something else.

Comment: Here is a link to a blog post talking about the issues that exists with @InjectMocks, it has the same recommendations as the accepted answer has: https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/

Comment: I ended up copying the Whitebox code too, it's a very simple class that streamlines what I needed to do. Here's the code, in case anyone else needs it https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mockito/mockito/fea4074f8d4a7b1f7b8e89d4819bef25b1b6228f/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/util/reflection/Whitebox.java

Comment: Here with [fest-reflect](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-reflect) api you can find an easy to use fluent API for reflection support. This is what I use as an alternative to Mockito's Whiltebox.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that `Whitebox` was always in the `org.mockito.internal` package. Beyond the incrementing of the major version number, the `internal` designation is a giveaway that the package may be subject to breaking changes.

If you do want to make it a point to set otherwise-inaccessible fields in your test, you can do so in the same way that `setInternalState` does, which is just to identify the field in the hierarchy, call `setAccessible` on it, and then set it. [The full code is here on grepcode.](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.10.19/org/mockito/internal/util/reflection/Whitebox.java?av=f#27) You can also examine a number of [other ways to set inaccessible state in tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27552765/1426891).

```
public static void setInternalState(Object target, String field, Object value) {
    Class<?> c = target.getClass();
    try {
        Field f = getFieldFromHierarchy(c, field);  // Checks superclasses.
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(target, value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "Unable to set internal state on a private field. [...]", e);
    }
}
```

**However,** in situations like this, my general advice is to *stop fighting the tools*: Java's four levels of encapsulation (public, protected, package, private) are not necessarily granular enough to express the degree of protection you're trying to express, and it's often much easier to add a well-documented initialization method or constructor override to override the dependencies as you're trying to do reflectively. If you put your tests in the same Java package as the class it tests, you can often even make the fields or method/constructor package-private, which is also a good reason to set up parallel source folders `src` and `tests` (etc) that represent two halves of the same Java package.

Though some treat this additional method or constructor as "API pollution", I see it instead as coding to the  requirements of one of your class's most important consumers—*its own test*. If you need a pristine external interface, you can easily define one separately such that you can hide any details you'd like. However, you may find you *like* the ability to inject any real or mock implementation directly into your now-more-flexible component, at which point you may want to look into dependency injection patterns or frameworks.

Comment: In cases like this, however, one should be able to use the `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` annotations, right? So, not the case of fighting the tool, but of not properly using what it provides.

Comment: @Rogério Depends on how comfortable you are with `@InjectMocks`'s caveats. I've seen enough problems with its use that I'm no longer recommending it myself. You're welcome to, though.

Comment: @Rogério - I used to think it was great (@InjectMocks), but after a while I started to see problems with this technique and started to use Whitebox, it gave better error messages if something was wrong.

Comment: You're probably right about `@InjectMocks`; indeed it's a feature that hasn't received much attention from Mockito developers. Of course, as JMockit's developer, I use the `@Tested` annotation which is much more advanced at this point 8^)

Comment: @JeffBowman I ended up copying the code for WhiteBox, as it could be done that way, and searched and replaced the importstatement. It is not a nice solution, since we have many modules, and I need to make it awailable in all modules. 

You have a good point in that tests is one of a class most important consumer; why not make it simpler for them?
Changeing the way to think is harder than changing technology - we will see how me and my colleges will do this in the future. I am not totaly convinced yet, I need to work with my self a bit first. Your philosophy It has its pro's.

Comment: Yes. At last I have to change `private` methods to "package" visibility and that just enables its usage in the tests. That seems the way with least impact. Thanks.

Comment: Mirror for Whitebox implementation: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/mockito/+/e0ae5d7e87b1dd6e789803c1b9615a84bd7488b7/src/org/mockito/internal/util/reflection/Whitebox.java

Answer (score 86):

If you are using Spring (the spring-test library specifically), you can simply use `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` instead of `Whitebox.setInternalState`

Comment: That would have been a better solution than copying the Whitebox code. I wish I knew about this class earlier :)

Comment: an example would be more helpful

Answer (score 11):

You can use FieldSetter in Mockito2.x

```
    import org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldSetter;
 FieldSetter.setField(eventHandler,eventHandler.getClass().getDeclaredField("securityService"), securityService);
```

Comment: Just as Whitebox, this class can suddenly change (since it is in the internal package). But this looks like the replacement for Whitebox in mockito.

Answer (score 10):

The cleanest, neatest and **most portable** way without reinventing the wheel is to use Apache Commons' `FieldUtils`.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html

The answer to your question would then be

```
public static void setStaticFieldValue(
        @NonNull final Class<?> clz,
        @NonNull final String fieldName,
        @NonNull final Object value) throws Exception {
    final Field f = FieldUtils.getField(clz, fieldName, true);
    FieldUtils.removeFinalModifier(f);
    f.set(null, value);
}
```

Comment: This! And the rest of the apache commons reflect docs (like `MethodUtils`, `ConstructorUtils`, ...) can be found here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/

Answer (score 2):

Here with [fest-reflect](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-reflect) api you can find an easy to use fluent API for reflection support. This is what I use as an alternative to Mockito's Whiltebox.

Answer (score 0):

The important distinction between plain old Java and plain new Java is `getDeclaredField/s` returns private fields.

```
public static Object getField(Object o, String name) {
    try {
        Field f = o.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        return f.get(o);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.info(o.getClass() + " " + name + " " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return null;
}

public static void setField(Object o, String name, Object value) {
    try {
        Field f = o.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(o, value);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.info(o.getClass() + " " + name + " " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

PowerMock has [Whitebox as part of its public API](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Bypass-Encapsulation). This is part of `powermock-reflect`.